# sqlalchemy-datatables TypeError: Object of type Customer is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use [SQLAlchemy-DataTables](https://github.com/Pegase745/sqlalchemy-datatables) to build a table with server-side processing,

```
   @app.route("/data", methods=['GET'])
        def data():
        columns = [
            ColumnDT(Customer.id),
            ColumnDT(Customer.Email),
        ]
        query = db.session.query(Customer)
        params = request.args.to_dict()
    
        
        rowTable = DataTables(params, query, columns)
        print(query , file=sys.stdout)
        return jsonify(rowTable.output_result())
```

while running in debug mode I can see that rowTable.output_result() returns:

```
{'draw': '1', 'recordsTotal': '13997', 'recordsFiltered': '13997', 'data': [{'0': <Customer#1>, '1': 1}, {'0': <Customer#2>, '1': 2}, {'0': <Customer#3>, '1': 3}, {'0': <Customer#4>, '1': 4}, {'0': <Customer#5>, '1': 5}, {'0': <Customer#6>, '1': 6}, {'0': <Customer#7>, '1': 7}, {'0': <Customer#8>, '1': 8}, {'0': <Customer#9>, '1': 9}, {'0': <Customer#10>, '1': 10}]}
```

but i get the following error:
TypeError: Object of type Customer is not JSON serializable

I did everything as per documentation so I can't figure out why this is not working

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to call `jsonify()` on the python object `<Customer>`. To see why this is, look at your output:

```
{
  'draw': '1',
  'recordsTotal': '13997',
  'recordsFiltered': '13997',
  'data': [{
    '0': < Customer1 > ,
    '1': 1
  }, {
    '0': < Customer2 > ,
    '1': 2
  }, {
    '0': < Customer3 > ,
    '1': 3
  }, {
    '0': < Customer4 > ,
    '1': 4
  }, {
    '0': < Customer5 > ,
    '1': 5
  }, {
    '0': < Customer6 > ,
    '1': 6
  }, {
    '0': < Customer7 > ,
    '1': 7
  }, {
    '0': < Customer8 > ,
    '1': 8
  }, {
    '0': < Customer9 > ,
    '1': 9
  }, {
    '0': < Customer10 > ,
    '1': 10
  }]
}
```

Inside `'data'` you have objects that cannot be automatically serialized by `json.dumps()` which is what `jsonify()` effectively does for you.

To fix this problem, you need to modify the output so that the `json.dumps()` has more boring data types to work with. For example:

```py
for item in rowTable.output_result()['data']:
    item['0'] = {
        'customer_id': item['0'].id,
        # and so on for the other properties you're interested in
    }
```

You could also write a function on the `<Customer>` class that automatically serializes all the important properties, and then you could just do something like:

```
for item in rowTable.output_result()['data']:
    item['0'] = item['0'].serialized
```

and the example for how to do that on the class:

```
class Customer(Model):
    id = Column(Integer)
    # etc...

    @property
    def serialized(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id
        }
```