# How to using sqlalchemy-datatables on Flask?

Tags: python, flask, datatables, sqlalchemy, jinja2

i'm very new with sqlalchemy-datatables and now i try to create html table which using datatables  plugin to contain data from database that i have query and this is my code.

routes.py

```
@app.route('/load_db', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def load_db():
    columns = [
        ColumnDT(Customers.customer_code),
        ColumnDT(Customers.customer_name),
    ]
    query = db.session.query(Customers)
    params = request.args.to_dict()

    rowTable = DataTables(params, query, columns)

    return jsonify(rowTable.output_result())
```

models.py

```
class Customers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    customer_code = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True)
    customer_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    customer_address = db.Column(db.String(200))
```

customer.html

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#customertable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/load_db"
      });

    });
```

When i render the template it error like this.

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Customers is not JSON serializable
```

This is the value of `rowTable.output_result()` when i print it out.

```
{'draw': '1', 'recordsTotal': '52', 'recordsFiltered': '52', 'data': [{'0': <Customers 1>, '1': '1'}, {'0': <Customers 10>, '1': '10'}, {'0': <Customers 11>, '1': '11'}, {'0': <Customers 12>, '1': '12'}, {'0': <Customers 13>, '1': '13'}, {'0': <Customers 14>, '1': '14'}, {'0': <Customers 15>, '1': '15'}, {'0': <Customers 16>, '1': '16'}, {'0': <Customers 17>, '1': '17'}, {'0': <Customers 18>, '1': '18'}]}
```

So what is a problem with my code and how can i fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlalchemy-datatables TypeError: Object of type Customer is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686951/sqlalchemy-datatables-typeerror-object-of-type-customer-is-not-json-serializabl)

Comment: @Agung Wiyono  Thank for response, but it not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change your query into this, `db.session.query().select_from(Customer)`. It's what written on sqlalchemy-datatables github page.

I don't have any explanation about what makes them different yet.

Comment: Sorry i got some more question, do you know how to add the button to each column which store `customer_code` of that row?

Comment: You may want to search *datatables render*. If you've tried that and still got question, then please post another question.